# Calculate Sum of a group of inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have few inputs this this:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
</form>
```

I need, on change or on keyup to update the sum of these inputs.

So my code is the following:

```
function updatePriceWithTaxe() {

    $('input[name=tax[]]').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    alert(sum);
}

$('input[name=tax[]]').on('change keyup', function() {
    updatePriceWithTaxe();
});
```

Do you know why it doesn't work please ?

The alert isn't fire and I have this error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name=STX_Amount[]`

Thanks.

Comment: "my code is the following: [...] Do you know why please ?" - well I guess you're the one who can answer this best. ;-)

Comment: @Connum, haha good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser parsing the selector gets confused by the square brackets denoting an attribute and the square brackets in the name. You have to enclose the name value in the attribute selector with double quotes.

```js
function updatePriceWithTaxe() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[name="tax[]"]').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });

  console.log(sum);
}

$('input[name="tax[]"]').on('change keyup', updatePriceWithTaxe);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="tax[]">
  <input type="number" name="tax[]">
  <input type="number" name="tax[]">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Type name with this structor (add **`"`** for name):

```
$('input[name="tax[]"]')
```

and `updatePriceWithTaxe()` should be change to:

```
function updatePriceWithTaxe() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name="tax[]"]').each(function(key, element) {
       sum += Number(element.value);
    });

    alert(sum);
}
```

:`var sum = 0` add to function, because each time `updatePriceWithTaxe()` is called, the value of the variable must be *0* and `sum` is calculated with new values

Comment: A Stack Overflow answer is regarded more helpful if it explains the reasons why the original code failed and what has been changed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do the sum then you can try like this:

```js
const taxInputElements = $('[name="tax[]"]');

taxInputElements.on('change keyup', function(event) {
      let sum = 0;
      taxInputElements.each(function(key, element) {
              sum += Number(element.value);
      });
      console.log("Current sum: " + sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
    <input type="number" name="tax[]">
</form>
```

Comment: Please check your code, it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @Connum fixed it

Comment: good, however, quoting from the question `"on change or on keyup"` ;-)

Comment: @Connum fixing it

Comment: You would also have to reset the sum inside the calculation function, otherwise it will just increase the number on and on

Comment: @Connum fixed it